# Keeping a global value in the next page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ecommerce site. I have a global variable named `cart` with dynamic value. I would like to keep the value of this variable in other pages and be `undfedined` and change it only if the value exist otherwise keep the previous value. How can I make it?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at javascript cookies or if you're using server side scripting like PHP look into sessions

Comment: You'll have to send the value over to the server and then return the value in the next request. Or you'll have to store it at client side, through HMTL 5 storage capacities. I would recommend the latter.